# Laravel 5 where method not working

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes, laravel-5

I'm trying to query records using a parameter from a route, but it's not working properly.

This is my route:

```
Route::get('reports/{id}', 'ReportsController@show');
```

This is my controller method:

```
public function show($id) {
    return Reports::all()->where('user_id', $id);
}
```

When accessing the route `'reports/1'`, it returns nothing. However, if I hardcode in the id to use in the method, it does work:

```
public function show($id) {
    return Reports::all()->where('user_id', 1);
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code, please help.

Comment: You're not creating or returning a view. In other words, you're not creating output by using `return`in the context you're trying to do it in.

Comment: @Repox this is a api model backend and im using angular to fetch data

Comment: You still don't return anything. Take a look at the [documentation on responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses).

Comment: @LokiSinclair and @Repox im new to laravel, i dont get it, when i return `return Reports::all()->where('user_id', 1 );` it returns a json but when i return `return Reports::all()->where('user_id', $id );` it returns only [ ].

Comment: return Reports::where('user_id', $id)->first();

Comment: if it's not return nothing,how could you know code is working?

Comment: Before the return statement put `dd($id);` What is the output from that?

Comment: Guys problem solved, its just a simple mistake, when i parse the $id into int   its working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're calling `where()` on a Laravel Collection, not on a Laravel Query Builder.

`Reports::all()` will run a query that will get every single report from the database and put it into a Collection. You're then running the `where()` method on that Collection.

The difference is that the `where()` method on a Collection loops through the items in the collection, and does a strict comparison (===), whereas the query builder adds a parameterized where clause to the SQL, which doesn't care about the variable type.

What you're running into is that when using the variable, you're running `where('user_id', '1')`, which is doing a strict comparison (===) of the `user_id` field to the string '1'. Since all the user ids are integers, you won't get any results.

What you really want to do is add your where conditions to the SQL statement. Instead of your current logic, you want:

```
public function show($id) {
    return Reports::where('user_id', $id)->get();
}
```

This will fix your issue, as well as only return those records that match your where clause, which may severely boost your performance. If you have a million reports, you don't want to build a collection of a million objects, and then iterate through them.